# Replace an extra number from date

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I have OCR extracted date string due to image quality second slash of date comes as 1,

i.e. date comes as 23/0212014 where 1 before year should be / actually. I have tried to replace 1 with regex but its not working.

`DateTime.TryParseExact` does not work and code i have tried is:

```
string mm = "23/0212014";
var rex = new Regex(@"(?:((\d{2}\/\d{2})1(\d{4})))");
mm = rex.Replace(mm, "");
```

How to convert it to proper date `(dd/MM/yyyy)`?

Comment: "DateTime.TryParseExact does not work" - what did you try do get it working?

Comment: Is it always 1 before year and the length of data string is 10?

Comment: If the current format of the string is fixed, you could very well replace the 5th char with '/'. And then use DateTime.TryParse(YOURSTRING)

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this. Test for the 5th char = `1` and replace with `/`

Comment: yes the second / will always be 1 only and will be just before year (yyyy) and length will always be 10.

With DateTime.TryParseExact I have format as:

string[] formats = {"dd/MM1yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/MMyyyy", "ddMMyyyy", "ddMM/yyyy"};

(check the first one)

Comment: @seopower: So what happened when you tried that? And were you specifying a culture? See my sample code which works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.TryParseExact` works fine for me:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "23/0212014";
        DateTime result;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "dd/MM'1'yyyy",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
23/02/2014 00:00:00
```

(Once you've parsed it as a `DateTime` you can reformat it however you want, of course.)

I would definitely try to use this rather than regular expressions.

Comment: Even the `'`s around the `1` are unnecessary; it'll be treated as a literal anyway.

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, but I make a habit of putting `'` round most literals in date/time patterns. I think it makes it clearer.